Recaptcha enterprise v3, finding action parameter
I am working on newsletters automations, but this washingtonPost is where I am stuck.
This website is using v3 captcha and I am using 2captcha service to solve captcha now one thing I am stuck here is, for solving the captcha v3 you need sitekey, pageurl, minscore and action parameter.
I have everything but this action parameters I cant find.
With this repo you can find the captcha detail but no luck with action parameter:
https://gist.github.com/2captcha/2ee70fa1130e756e1693a5d4be4d8c70
Site:
https://www.washingtonpost.com/newsletters/
Any help will be appreciated.

Have you tried checking in the Network tab using  browser inspect. Sometimes, the action parameter might be passed to the reCAPTCHA function through inline JavaScript. Check this blog which helps to understand more in detail.

Yes I did, but nothing found there.

You can try these troubleshooting steps to find action parameter:
Try to Inspect the Website’s Network Traffic by using the browser development tools inspect option.Reload the page and look for requests made to reCAPTCHA API. Most of the time these requests will contain the action parameter.
As per this blog

Action is a new parameter that allows processing user actions on the website differently. To find this we need to inspect the javascript code of the website looking for call of grecaptcha.execute function. Example:
grecaptcha.execute("6Lc2fhwTAAAAAGatXTzFYfvlQMI2T7B6ji8UVV_f", {action: something})

You might need to check all javascript files. You can  try to find the value of action parameter inside ___grecaptcha_cfg configuration object. Also we can call grecaptcha.execute and inspect javascript code. The API will use "verify" default value it if we won`t provide action in our request.

Refer to this blog by Ethan Collins for more information. Check this official recaptcha documentation for more information on actions.
NOTE: If you are willing to use a third party proxy then you can try using Charles proxy.
